# Horizontal stackview label grow with a fixed height element

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a horizontal stackview with a **UIImageView** (1:1 Aspect Rati, Height 32) and a **label**. Since it has a height the stackView cuts off my label on the right not letting me have more than one line.

[image]

I want the Horizontal StackView grow in height as the labels need to display its own text or use the UIImageView height if its bigger.

[image]

Comment: Show me your view hierarchy and constraints. BTW I dont think it is good to use stack

Comment: updated @dahiya_boy

Comment: it seems 2 elements inside the horizontal stackview can't have different heights

Comment: Use Bottom Constraint too For Stackview

Comment: no, i want the stackview to grow as its content. @SagarShirbhate

Comment: Can you check this project I've prepared just now? https://www.dropbox.com/s/dehizstq39oggh4/Deneme.zip?dl=0

Comment: @emreoktem already checked. It doesn't work. If you want your imageView height to 32 as i need to be,  the label on the right also collapses.

Comment: @Godfather It Will Work As I see an answer Bottom constraint is also added and its simple :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is the complete explanation,

If you do not give any height to the Imageview then how it looks like

[image]

> ImageView grows

If you give height to the Imageview,

[image]

> Label shrinks to the height of imageview

### **Solution**

Put ImageView Inside a view like below,

[image]

Now, give proper constraints to the imageview. Now it works properly.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: so now you need to give constraints horizontally cause neither the imageview and label have those, isnt? But yeah thats exactly the problem.

Comment: @Godfather the label isn't inside the view. Only the image

Comment: you lost the easy setup of the horizontal stack view, in fact theres no need for that since you just put everything inside a uiview, not just the imageiview, also the label

Comment: can you share the project?

Comment: @Godfather I didnt prepared any project for this, it is simple, instead of imageview first take UIView and then put a ImageView in it & give constraints. Thats all

Comment: @Godfather I've edited to include an image showing the new constraints you'll need for the `imageview` and the `uiview`

Comment: @Godfather add `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` constraints of the `imageView` to the `view` of `zero`. But be sure to change the `bottom` constraint to `>=` relationship

Comment: @SylvanDAsh no need of the bottom >= .

Comment: @SylvanDAsh yeah, the >= was the thing i missed. With this it works

Comment: @dahiya_boy the `bottom >=` is necessary so that the `label's` height can adjust the overall height of the stackview

Comment: @SylvanDAsh Check my constraints -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHDna.png

Answer (score 6):

GitHub Repo: [Source Code](https://github.com/dep2k/ExpandableStackView.git)
Check the code inside FirstViewController

Explanation:

**Step 1:**
Change the constraint of StackView, such that **height >= minValue** value. After that it's height will auto adjust depending on the height of the UILabel.

**Step 2:**
Call sizeToFit method of the UILabel after you set it's text. That will change the frame of the UILabel.

```
lable.text = "SomeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView.omeText Here. It will expalnd the StackView."
lable.sizeToFit()
```

**Step 3:**
Set the Scale Mode of image to Aspect Fit, and set it's height and width constraint.

**Step 4:**
Set the alignment of Stackview as per the requirement, I have set set it to top to make the image and Label to stay at the top.

**Final Result:**

[image: StackViewLayout with adjustable height]

Constraints:

[image]

Comment: wich constraint?

Comment: heightConstaint on the UIStackView.

Comment: i added a height constraint to the stackView, to be greater than or equal min height (32) but still doesnt grow.

Comment: @DeepArora But it increases the height of Imageview also.

Comment: @Godfather Remove the height of ImageView and If there is any height of StackView then make it >= . Now check

Comment: I dont want to remove the height o the ImageView, otherwise it grows also.

Comment: can you share this project?

Comment: Added the GitHub link, let me know if that still doesn't solve your problem, and if it does, please access my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Beautifully explained, worked perfectly. Thank you